# Atiyah and Macdonald Proposition 10.15

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In Proposition 10.15, let $A$ be Noetherian ring and $\hat{A}$ be $\frak{a}$- adic completion , and we can also complete $\frak{a}$ as $A$ - module to $\hat{\frak{a}}$ with the isomorphism that $\hat{\frak{a}} \cong \hat{A}\otimes_A \frak{a}$

then the book says that since $\hat{A}$ is complete under $\hat{\frak{a}}$- topology(I know why it's complete) then for any $x \in \hat{\frak{a}}$ the $$(1-x)^{-1} = 1+x+x^2+....$$

converge so $(1-x)$ is a unit.

there are two question

- why $1+x+x^2...$ converge if $\hat{A}$ is complete in $\hat{\frak{a}}$ topology
- why the infinite sequence $1+x+x^2+...$ is the inverse of $(1-x)$?

I can't make it clear.

Comment: In analysis we know complete means Cauchy sequence converge, however here the book didn't prove that completeness in the commutative algebraic sense implies the Cauchy sequence converge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I can answer my question now:

for the first question by definition $G$ is complete if canonical map $G\to \hat{G}$ is isomorphism, I adopt the definition for $\hat{G}$ to be set of equivalent Cauchy sequence, then we see since the map is surjective we have a point $y\in G$ such that the constant sequence $(y) $ is equivalent to the sequence $(\sum^n_{i=0}x^i)$ ,and easy to check that $y$ is the convergent point of the Cauchy sequence.

Therefore we see the completeness in the commutative algebraic definition immediately implies the Cauchy sequence will converge.

---

For the second question see answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1077377/360262)